# Why i get the same value for all the different maturities?

Tags: python, pandas, function, if-statement

DateFrame df  that i got from webscraping :

- Date d'échéance : due date
- Transaction : Transaction
- Taux moyen pondéré : weighted average rate
- Date de la valeur : value date
- maturite : maturity  (calculated)

I should add column to my dataframe df called " Taux act" :

- If Maturity 'maturite' > 1 YEAR : Taux act = weighted average rate 'Taux moyen pondéré'
- If Maturity < 1 YEAR  : Taux act =  ((1 + weighted average rate maturity)/360)**(365/maturity)-1

Dataframe df :
|Date d'échéance|Transaction|Taux moyen pondéré|Date de la valeur| maturite |taux  |
|---------------|-----------|------------------|-----------------|----------|----- |
|  2019-04-14   |  104.47   |       2.300      |  2019-03-18     |  27 days |7.59..|
|2019-05-20 |    71.28  |       2.333      |  2019-03-11     |  70 days |7.59..|

Comment: The table is not formatted properly when viewing it but is correctly formatted when editing it, is it a problem with Stack Overflow?

Comment: @AshokArora so ?